# Not getting location selected value in controller

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework

I am using this http://jsfiddle.net/moinsam/SDPHm/light/ for getting location.

```
<input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" ng-model=show.location>
<button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="sendReshedule(show)">Reshedule</button>
$scope.sendReshedule = function(data){
console.log(data);
}
```

I am searching location using the input box and when the list appears I select one location
But the problem is that the letter I have typed in the textbox I can access that only in the controller but not the actual selected location. 
I am not able to access the selected location.

**For Example**.: I typed "**cal**" and I get a list of suggestions.Now I select "**california Los Angeles**". 
This selection gets display in the input box but when I am trying to access the text of input box I am not getting full value, I am getting only "**cal**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one quick fix is `console.log(document.getElementById('searchTextField').value);`
vl keep looking other ways.

**Reason** : Angular binds `show` to ng-model then `show` gets value as `cal` when u type, but when google maps javascript updates it's value ie `california` which is not a angular part , angular doesn't know that it has to update it's `show` ng-model value , so u get it as `cal` , for this we use `$scope.$apply()` however recent angular fixes it with monkey patch.

vl try to post a working piece of code , hope this helps

other way for this is to create a custom element:  [working fiddle for this approach](http://jsfiddle.net/mwDQr/1/)